# Spring Bean injection in web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, autowired

When request is processed by spring controller, the service is not wired:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Inject
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session){
        try {
            ...
            //Next line throws NullPointerException, this.accountService is null
            Account account = this.accountService.login(username, password);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            request.setAttribute("exception", e);
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

AccountService and its only implementation are defined in module `service` as:

```
package com.savdev.springmvcexample.service;
...
public interface AccountService {
```

...

```
package com.savdev.springmvcexample.service;
@Service("accountService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
```

The web configuration is loaded by files, located in `web` module:

```
    package com.savdev.springmvcexample.web.config;
    public class SpringMvcExampleWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer 

{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(WebMvcContextConfiguration.class);
        ...
    }
    private WebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(annotatedClasses);
        return context;
    }
```

The WebMvcContextConfiguration file that scans packages to discovery beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.savdev.springmvcexample.web", "com.savdev.springmvcexample.service" })
public class WebMvcContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

This class is loaded, cause view resolving is used according to InternalResourceViewResolver logic. As a result the "com.savdev.springmvcexample.web" is scanned cause controller that processes request is found.

The "com.savdev.springmvcexample.service" is scanned, but it is in another module, I don't know can it be an issue or not, but I don't get any errors.

**UPDATED:**

@JBNizet, module - means module in maven multimodule project. I've removed @Repository and now I'm getting an error in test:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency.

That means, that means the spring profile is not activated. DataSource is loaded only for profiles.

In web infrastructure I manage profiles with:

```
public class SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext ctx) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = ctx.getEnvironment();
        List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<String>(getProfiles());
        if( profiles == null || profiles.isEmpty() )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Profiles have not been configured");
        }
        environment.setActiveProfiles(profiles.toArray( new String[0]));
    }

    //TODO add logic
    private Collection<String> getProfiles() {
        return Lists.newArrayList("file_based", "test_data");
    }
}
```

If I'm not wrong SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer is used before Spring ApplicationContext is loaded. And it is made automatically. Nothing additional has to be configured for this. But it's not working. Please fix me, if I'm wrong.

Please note, the initializer has the following signature:

```
SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext>
```

At the moment when DispatcherServlet is configured I can setup it using:

```
setContextInitializers(ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>... contextInitializers)
```

How can I setup setContextInitializers but pass something that implements `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext>`, but not `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>`

Comment: What do you call "module"? Is it "package"? And why is your service annotated with @Repository? It shouldn't.

Comment: @JBNizet, module - module of multimodule maven project, I've removed the '@Repository', and updated my question. Cannot insert it here.

Answer (score 0):

@Inject requires the presence of the JSR 330 jar on the classpath. It could be that it's visible at compile time but not at runtime.

Try this:

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private AccountService accountService;
```

If this does not work, it means that the bean AccountServiceImpl is not being scanned correctly.

If it does work, it means that there is a problem with @Inject support (maybe a missing jar at runtime).

If the scanning is not working, try to do the scanning via xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.savdev.springmvcexample.service" />
```

Can you post back:

- If @Autowired(required=true) works
- if and how the JSR-330 is added in the poms (output of mvn dependency:tree)
- did the scanning via xml worked